# Create a doc file from Access OLE Object and display it using a WebBrowser control

Tags: vb.net, .htaccess

My Access database contains an OLE Object "Microsoft Word 97 - 2003". This is my attempt at writing the OLE Object to a .doc file, and displaying it in a WebBrowser control:

Private Sub LoadBlob(objDataTable As DataTable)

```
    Dim WordBlob() As Byte = Nothing
    Dim TrimWordBlob() As Byte = Nothing
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim objStream As Stream

    Try
        If objDataTable(0).Item("DescriptionWord") IsNot DBNull.Value Then
            WordBlob = CType(objDataTable(0).Item("DescriptionWord"), Byte())
        End If
        FileName = libGlobal.App_Path & "\temp.doc"

        TrimWordBlob = New Byte(WordBlob.Length - 86) {}
        Buffer.BlockCopy(WordBlob, 85, TrimWordBlob, 0, TrimWordBlob.Length)
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(FileName, TrimWordBlob)

        objStream = New MemoryStream(TrimWordBlob)
        objStream.Position = 0
        Me.wbrDocument.DocumentStream = objStream

    Catch ex As Exception
        libError.ShowErrorMessage(ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

The Temp.doc is not a valid Word Document, and the WebBrowser control does not show anything.
Could you show me the error of my ways?

Comment: I wouldn't think that a WebBrowser control would display a Word document. Can you use the program registered to display .doc files? 
  Process.start(FileName)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think is works for Word files but a technique I use for HTA type browsing is to build the text for the .hta file, save the file, and use Process.Start().  Here's an .hta file that would open a file (if that is ever useful.) Typically the URL would just be a typical URL for a document type supported by HTA.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
 <!--intro: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496(v=vs.85).aspx-->
 <!--ref:   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536473(v=VS.85).aspx-->
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Your Page Title</title>
   <hta:application id="oMyApp" 
     applicationname="EnvView" 
     border="thin"
     caption="yes"
     showintaskbar="yes"
     minimizeButton="yes"
     singleinstance="yes"
     sysmenu="yes"
     windowstate="maximize"
     navigable="yes" >
     <!--use title="none" for full desktop - use Alt-F4 to close-->
 <meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=file://filepath"></HEAD>
 <BODY>
 if load fails use Alt-F4 to close
 </BODY>
 </HTML>
```